# CSS - background not working in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, background-image

I'm trying to get a background image to work in all browsers. The following code works perfectly for every browser but Firefox:

```
<style>
    body {
        background: url('src/images/SpeqS.jpg') no-repeat center;
        background-size: 50%;
        height: 100%;
    }
</style>
```

Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: In which Firefox version do you run this code ?  background-size will only work in FF4+. You have to add -moz prefix for earlier versions : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I'm running FF 45.0.2 so it should work.

Comment: Please make a jsfiddle to show us what's happening?

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't know if that was useful as I only use html.
https://jsfiddle.net/w79tew87/6/ this actually doesnt seem to work..

In chrome (and others) it looks like this: http://imgur.com/cZykHTI
In ff it looks like this: http://imgur.com/XRqqwlv

Answer (score 0):

Updated code try this 
`body {
        background: url('src/images/SpeqS.jpg') no-repeat center center;
        -webkit-background-size: cover;
        -moz-background-size: cover;
        -o-background-size: cover;
        background-size: cover;
        height: 100%;
    }`

Comment: I tried this, the image shows up on the top left corner of the screen and it seems to fall past the edges:
http://i.imgur.com/XRqqwlv.png
It should look like this, like it does in chrome:
http://i.imgur.com/cZykHTI.png

I've tried changing multiple of those background specifications but it seems most of the specifications make the image not appear at all.

Comment: Try adding image separately `background-image:url('src/images/SpeqS.jpg'); background-position: center;background-size: 50%;background-repeat:no-repeat `.

Comment: Tried this as well, but as I said; changing more specifications besides background background-image seems to make the image disappear.

Comment: Did you specify the correct html doc type? `<!DOCTYPE html>` like this for html5

Comment: Yes, that is specified

Answer (score 0):

```
 body {
background: url('http://s32.postimg.org/pqht43fkl/Speq_S.jpg') no-repeat top center;
background-size: 50%;
height: 100%;
```

}

This is working fine in the jsfiddle. Hope it's the result you are looking for.

Comment: In firefox, this works in the jsfiddle. It doesn't work in the actual code for me. Can it have something to do with where it is specified in my code? Currently, I have style tags in my html for the home page and there I specify the background. This is because this works well with the welcome and custome name text on the home page. Does it need to be in my css file?